# Showing that a function series is positive

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem. Let $w$ be the function defined on $\mathbb R$ by
$$
w(x) = \left( 1-x^2\right) \exp(-x^2/2) \quad ,\quad x\in\mathbb R\;,
$$
and a real number $\phi >1$ .

Let $f$ be the function defined as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\phi^{-k} w(\phi^{-k}x) \;.
$$
The function $f$ is well defined since the boundedness of $w$ is a sufficient condition for this series to be normal.

The question is the following: show that $f$ is positive on $\mathbb R$. I unfortunately have no clue to start this problem.

Comment: It looks false. Numerically, $f(x)$ appears to be negative ($-0.005\ldots$)  in a neighbourhood of $x=4.5$ when $\phi=2$.